# How to deploy gulp-ftp, after previos task?

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, npm-scripts

i have a problem with two gulp task in npm.js. First task compile project, next tast deploy it on ftp. If I run them separately - all work, but when i try to use them together, its now work. I think its a stream error. Cuz gulp ftp (second task) finish faster then (first task). Can someone help with this?

First task:

```
gulp.task('build', ['nib', 'html', 'scripts'], function() {
    var removeDist = del.sync('app/dist');

    var buildCSS = gulp
        .src('app/chache/css/*.css')
        .pipe(cssnano())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/dist/css'));

    var buildImg = gulp
        .src(['app/html-dev/img/**/*', '!app/html-dev/img/empty.jpg'])
        .pipe(imagemin({
            interlaced: true,
            progressive: true,
            svgoPlugins: [{ removeViewBox: false }],
            une: [pngquant()]
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/dist/img'));

    var buildFonts = gulp
        .src(["app/html-dev/fonts/**/*", '!app/html-dev/fonts/empty.woff'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/dist/fonts'));

    var buildJS = gulp
        .src("app/chache/js/**/*")
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/dist/js'));

    var buildHhtml = gulp
        .src("app/chache/*.html")
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/dist'));
});
```

Ftp Task:

```
gulp.task('ftp', ['build'], function () {
    return gulp.src('app/dist/**')
        .pipe(ftp(ftpinfo))
        // you need to have some kind of stream after gulp-ftp to make sure it's flushed 
        // this can be a gulp plugin, gulp.dest, or any kind of stream 
        // here we use a passthrough stream 
        .pipe(gutil.noop());
});
```

Error:

```
[13:34:47] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\test-dist\gulpfile.js
[13:34:47] Starting 'nib'...
[13:34:47] Starting 'html'...
[13:34:47] Starting 'scripts'...
[13:34:47] Finished 'scripts' after 9.31 ms
[13:34:50] Finished 'nib' after 3.35 s
[13:34:50] Finished 'html' after 3.34 s
[13:34:50] Starting 'build'...
[13:34:50] Finished 'build' after 21 ms
[13:34:50] Starting 'ftp'...
[13:34:50] gulp-ftp: No files uploaded
[13:34:50] Finished 'ftp' after 6.5 ms
[13:34:50] gulp-imagemin: Minified 0 images
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `return` the stream from the dependancy task, `'build'`. Otherwise the parent task `'ftp'` won't wait for `'build'`to end.

Since that task has multiple `src` you need to merge them with [`merge-stream`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-stream)

```
var merge = require('merge-stream');

gulp.task('build', ['nib', 'html', 'scripts'], function() {
    var removeDist = del.sync('app/dist');

    return merge(
    gulp
        .src('app/chache/css/*.css')
        .pipe(cssnano())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/dist/css')),

    gulp
        .src(['app/html-dev/img/**/*', '!app/html-dev/img/empty.jpg'])
        .pipe(imagemin({
            interlaced: true,
            progressive: true,
            svgoPlugins: [{ removeViewBox: false }],
            une: [pngquant()]
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/dist/img')),

    gulp
        .src(["app/html-dev/fonts/**/*", '!app/html-dev/fonts/empty.woff'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/dist/fonts')),

    gulp
        .src("app/chache/js/**/*")
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/dist/js')),

    gulp
        .src("app/chache/*.html")
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/dist'))
    );

});
```